# ontouch function not being fired on iPhone simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, dom-events, ios-simulator, iphone-4

On the iPhone Simulator, the event callback for `ontouch` doesn't seem to be working.

The following does not seem to work on my simulator:

```
document.ontouch = function() {
    alert('it works!');
}
```

Although this does return true:

```
if ('ontouch' in document) {
    alert('touch supported');
}
```

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 touch related events:

1. ontouchstart
2. ontouchmove
3. ontouchend

Try it with these and it should be OK!

Some good examples can be found with this article:

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/